# Dynamically changing JSS values when using withStyles() in material-ui

Tags: material-ui, jss

I have a Drawer component that is wrapped using withStyles and overrides some values on the anchorLeft className. 

`<Drawer anchor="left" classes={{paper: this.props.classes.paper, anchorLeft: this.props.classes.anchorLeft}} ...>`

I have some other parts of the app that can effect the `top` value that needs to be passed to `anchorLeft`. I am using redux so the top value is being passed through the redux store and sent to my Drawer component through props, so I need a way in the component to effect the anchorLeft top value.

What's the preferred way to do dynamic styling inside the component and change the values in the JSS style sheet? Is there a way to use the JSS sheet.update() and get access to the sheet that way? http://cssinjs.org/json-api?v=v9.0.0-pre.3#function-values

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using react-jss or styled-jss, in both cases you can use function values and you receive props there already.

Comment: I'm just using the default withStyles() that ships with material-ui. I tried a function value and don't see the function ever being called.

Answer (score 0):

Appears as of right now, it's not possible to do with the material-ui `withStyles`. I had to add react-jss and use `injectStyles` in the components I needed the dynamic functions, and then add an additional `ThemeProvider` that took the same theme as `MuiThemeProvider` so both material-ui and react-jss themes had the same setup.

Issue that's currently being tracked for material-ui related to this functionality: 
https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/7633